# Replacing values in a data array (B) based on conditions in another data array (A)

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm working on a 3D data array `A` of hourly rainfall that looks like the following:

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 1464, lat: 5, lon: 4)>
dask.array<getitem, shape=(1464, 5, 4), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1, 5, 4)>
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 34.39 34.38 34.37 34.36 34.35
  * lon      (lon) float64 132.7 132.7 132.7 132.7
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-06-01 ... 2018-07-31T23:00:00
Attributes:
    transform:      (0.012500000000000004, 0.0, 118.0, 0.0, -0.00833333313486...
    crs:            +init=epsg:4612
    res:            (0.012500000000000004, 0.008333333134861565)
    is_tiled:       1
    nodatavals:     (-9999.0,)
    scales:         (1.0,)
    offsets:        (0.0,)
    AREA_OR_POINT:  Area
```

I want to find out where the cumulative rainfall for certain time `"cumulative" = 0` and create a new 3D data array `B` that shows `1 if "cumulative"> 1, else 0`.

This is what I tried so far:
I created a np zeros (`name = B`) of same shape like `A` data array and assigned the same dims, coords, and attrs.

```
B = xr.DataArray(np.zeros(shape=(1464, 5, 4)), 
                       dims=A.dims,
                       coords = A.coords,
                       attrs = A.attrs       
                      )
print (B)

<xarray.DataArray (time: 1464, lat: 5, lon: 4)>
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

   ...,

   [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 34.39 34.38 34.37 34.36 34.35
  * lon      (lon) float64 132.7 132.7 132.7 132.7
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-06-01 ... 2018-07-31T23:00:00
Attributes:
    transform:      (0.012500000000000004, 0.0, 118.0, 0.0, -0.00833333313486...
    crs:            +init=epsg:4612
    res:            (0.012500000000000004, 0.008333333134861565)
    is_tiled:       1
    nodatavals:     (-9999.0,)
    scales:         (1.0,)
    offsets:        (0.0,)
    AREA_OR_POINT:  Area
```

Then, I used .where() function to change the values in `B` data array based on conditions in the `A` data array. (here I meant that if the cumulative rainfall for 10 hours is > 0, change the values of B data array for these 10 hours to 1)

```
for i in range(1464):
    B.where((A.isel(time=slice(i-9,i+1)).sum() > 0), 1)
```

BUT this function does not change any things in the `B` data array.

I am not sure whatever the use of `.where()` function is possible in my case.

If you have any idea how to make it, please let me know!

Comment: For creating these cumulative aggregations, look into [rolling window operations](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html?highlight=rolling#rolling-window-operations). And to create simple boolean datasets, you can use normal boolean operations and multiply the result with 1, giving you a binary dataset

Comment: What if you reassign like: B = B.where((A.isel(time=slice(i-9,i+1)).sum() > 0), 1)  It should change values for B.